# Why is it more secure to store data in xml when using php?

Tags: php, xml, security

I'm wondering if anyone can help shed some light on how PHP becomes more secure when you format various portions of pages in XML for later extraction and use.  Basically we have as our setup a function in "index.php" which is responsible for creating pages.  When called, it goes and grabs a series of XML files which contain database connection info and site setup.  It then parses these things into an array for use in the code.  Subsequently, the same thing is done for the overall page setup and widget setup.

Now I'll admit, I plain just don't like XML.  Far too verbose for any potential benefit, and a poor choice for data storage in general (why not just use a database?), but my colleague insists that our code is somehow more secure because of the XML.  He hasn't explained why, but is nonetheless convinced.  Any ideas why this may be the case?

What's even worse, the XML files are parsed into global variables, seems like if an exploit got into the index, all the attacker would need to do is loop through $GLOBALS to retrieve database credentials and other valuable info on our code.  Seems like this defeats any possible benefit of storing data in the XML.  So what am I missing here?  Any thoughts?

Comment: This question boils down to "Why does my colleague believe something that is broadly untrue?", and requires a lot of speculation. The only person who could, logically, provide an unarguably correct answer is your colleague.

Comment: That's a good point.  Guess I'll have to pin him down on it one of these days.  I was asking here more for the sake of getting some general considerations out in the open.  If it really is a case-by-case implementation sort of thing, there's obviously not much anyone who doesn't have all the details could say.

Answer (score 4):

XML files are not inherently secure or insecure, it's how they are used. XML is just a data format. In this case, it does not sound like how the data is separated contributes anything significantly to security.

Direct answer: it's not.

Answer (score 0):

I know I said this is speculation, but what the heck.

Firstly, you can't use a database to store its own database connection info, so that bit has to be somewhere. Deceze is correct that XML is not inherently secure.

Any security aspects will come from some other detail of how XML files are treated differently to the PHP in your organisation. The two things I can think of are:

1. if different people are allowed to edit the XML than the PHP, including if there is a nice frontend for editing and saving them
2. if all the website files are synced or backed up with a location that may be compromised (eg GitHub, USB thumb drive), you want to exclude sensitive stuff like db password, so it's easy to use the file extension .xml to filter files for exclusion.

Of course, these could apply to a .json or .csv file just as easily, or indeed .php files in separate folders.

One final thing XML has going for it is that:

- If someone faffs about with the file without knowing what they're doing they could break it fairly easily, which would then not parse, and the whole system would fail. Upshot: some people are put off from messing with the XML. I'm not sure that counts as security, but it is plausible in a world of colleagues with ambiguous motives.